# Time Division Multiplexing: Frame rate and bit rate

Tags: frame-rate, multiplexing

Can someone explain to me how to get the answer I am so lost.

**Q1.** A multiplexer combines four 100-kbps channels using a time slot of 2 bits. 
What is the frame rate and the bit rate?

The answer is **50,000 Frame per sec** and **400 kbps**.

Comment: 4 * 100kbps = ?. 100kbps / 2b = ?

Comment: oh ok i get it, but how do you turn 50,000 fps to 400 kbps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4 * 100kbps = 400kbps

100kbps / 2b = 100000bps / 2b = 50000fps

Answer (score 1):

```
bit rate = no. of channels * Input bit rate
```

So, `bit rate = 4 * 100kbps = 400kbps`

```
Frame rate = Input bit rate (convert it into bit) / time slot bit(s)
```

So, `Frame rate = 100000bps / 2b = 50000 frames per second (Frames/s)`

Answer (score -1):

Frame rate is the number of frames per second.
If we have 400000 bits per second transmission
Since each frame carries 8 bits, the frame rate would be:
400000/8 = 5000 per second.